# How to use juju with a VPS host?

Tags: juju, vps

Is possible to use juju with a VPS hosting provider?
I think "local enviroment" is the most close option, but I realize that is not possible to have access to it through other enveriments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now is possible with manual provisioning:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/clouds-manual

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/clouds-LXD

Depending on the provider of your VPS you may have some problems to configure a network-bridge i.e. if your VPS is running on a container-virtualization-software.
Also you have to download a lot of files, so you have to take a look at your disk-space and your traffic-limit.

If you can verify that the above will not cause any problems you can give the local environment a try.

Comment: I can't use the full features of juju with the local enviroment in a VPS.